# what is the meaning of circles near allied portraits in LoL

Tags: league-of-legends

In the in-game gui, there is a circle near each allied portrait. I've seen it be either gray or green; what is the meaning of that circle? As far as I know, it's not saying whether the friend is connected. (On that note, how can I find out how many players are currently playing in game? (i.e., how many are disconnected?)

[image]

In this picture, the first circle is black/gray and the rest three are green.

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: screenshot added.

Comment: Whoa! That picture is ancient!

Comment: @raven just found that in google images, I didn't have time to play a full game just for a screenshot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the ultimate indicators! If they are full and green, it means that character's ultimate is ready to be used.

As far as I know, there is no in-game way to determine if your allies have disconnected or not.

Comment: Ooh, this is actually a cool thing to learn. Sure helps more than relying on forgetful teammates to cry out "Ult up!"