# What does the green diamond beneath the character mean?

Tags: dota-2

[image]

Sometimes they are lit, sometimes they aren't.  What does that represent?

Comment: As a guess, does it mean that they have their ultimate ready?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an indicator whether or not their ultimate is up.

If the gem is blue, it indicates that the ultimate is off cooldown, but they don't currently have the mana to cast it (credit to @Decency)

[League of Legends has something similar.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/what-is-the-meaning-of-circles-near-allied-portraits-in-lol)

Comment: "Apparently I need another sentence so I don't get this automatically converted to a comment, but that's really all there is to it." Woah wait what?!

Comment: @Mana Yeah. Before it just wouldn't let you post if the algorithm thought you didn't meet the guidelines. Now it posts it *as a comment*. Check the deleted comments on the OP.

Comment: Wait, I can see deleted comments?! What?!

Comment: @Mana *Now* who's the terrible mod? Arda, of course. >.>

Comment: What if the gem is blue? As I've seen Clockwerk's being blue before.

Comment: wow that's nifty, I'll have to pay more attention to it now.

Comment: If the gem is blue it indicates that they have their ultimate off cooldown but don't presently have the mana to cast it.